# ImageResizer simply not resizing images

Tags: imageresizer

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 project, and I installed the ImageResizer Mvc Web.Config package, which added all necessary components, and modified my Web.Config file for me.

I have the following code in my MVC View:

```
<div id="heroimage" class="slideshow">
    <div>[LEFT]</div
    <div>[RIGHT]</div>
    <div>[INDICATOR]</div>
    @foreach (ICMSElement oHeroImage in Model.Elements("HeroImage")){
        <img src="images/@oHeroImage.Value" />       
    }
</div>

<div id="image-strip" class="viewer">
    <div class="slider">
        <ul>
            @foreach (ICMSElement oHeroImage in Model.Elements("HeroImage")){
                <li><img src="images/@oHeroImage.Value?width=100&height=100"></li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The images contained in the second div are not being resized. There is no css for the width and height that would be overriding the resizing.

In the troubleshooting page for the ImageResizer, it is stated that if an image cannot be resized, it could be one of the following causes:

**You did not register the HttpModule properly in both places of your Web.config file.**

(I used the NuGet package that modified the Web.Config for me)

**You are using IIS 6 (or earlier), or IIS7 Classic Pipeline, and are not using the .jpg.ashx syntax, and you have not mapped all requests to the ASP.NET runtime.**

(My IIS server is running IIS 7 in Integrated mode)

**You are using ASP.NET MVC (and have conflicting routes), but do not have the MvcRoutingShim plugin installed.**

(The MvcRoutingShim plugin is installed according to the debug page)

**You are mistyping the querystring commands.**

(I am not doing this in the code snippet above)

**The original image is smaller than the size you are requesting, and you are not using &scale=both (The default behavior is to never upscale images, but this can be changed)**

(The default image size in this case is 1280x800)

My Resizer.Debug output is here: https://gist.github.com/Thoth2020/11197160

My website is using a base tag in the Layout page, however it is not adjusting the src attribute of the img. For example, the page I am looking at renders this img tag:

```
<img src="images/00100010_1200_800_slideshow_03.jpg?width=100&height=100">
```

Which is the same as the snippet above with the Razor syntax interpreted.

So, I guess I am at a loss as to why this is not functioning correctly.

Comment: It sounds like some other module or handler is intercepting the requests before ImageResizer can deal with them. Have you tried the .ashx syntax to see if that fails? I.e, "images/00100010_1200_800_slideshow_03.jpg.ashx?width=100&height=100"

Comment: If all I do is add .ashx to the image right before the query string, I do see a broken image, and when I go to "Open Image in new tab" I see the IIS Exception. Now, was there something I was supposed to do besides just add the .ashx suffix to the img src tag? I am looking through the ImageResizer support section. At any rate, the exception I am getting looks like one of the site's existing controllers is trying to get ahold of this and then exceptioning out.

Comment: I added the tag <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" /> to the resizer section in Web.Config, and I still get the error, so I don't know if that was going to help me. At any rate, I put the IIS error message in a gist here: https://gist.github.com/Thoth2020/11223241 What I am trying to figure out is if it's the existing code that grabs onto it (that AssetController) or that MvcHandler. I guess the question is, is there a way that I can get ImageResizer to grab this request first?

Comment: Just an update, I found the part of the MVC application that is trying to grab the image. What it does (or tries to do, it exceptions out because it can't find a file on disk ending with .ashx) is return a FilePathResult whenever it sees an image. I am guessing that the moment it gets ahold of this, ImageResizer never has a chance to see it. Do you know any way I can force ImageResizer to be the one that handles the request?

Comment: Alternatively, is there code I can put into the Controller that is grabbing the request so that I can route it to ImageResizer?

Comment: It sounds like ImageResizer's 'stop routing' route is being registered after yours. Try calling `Config.Current.Plugins.LoadPlugins()` before route tables are populated, it may help. Better yet, eliminate the controller and action that are conflicting.

Comment: Sadly, I cannot eliminate the controller and action that are grabbing the image. To make a long story short, the images have to be handled a special way, and every image has to pass through this controller. In the CMS we use, the images are not actually stored at the location in the img tag, they have to go through a bit of transform. I'm pretty sure this approach is wholly incompatible with the ImageResizer plugin. We took an image that DOESN'T go through this transform and it resizes perfectly. I've contacted the support of the CMS to see if they can say anything.

Comment: Typically an [IVirtualImageProvider](http://imageresizing.net/docs/extend/virtualimageprovider) is the solution here. We have wide [CMS support](http://imageresizing.net/docs/workswith), it's possible an adapter has already been written.

Comment: The CMS is Ingeniux, and I didn't see an adapter on the community section of the ImageResizer web page. I tried implementing an IVirtualImageProvider here: https://gist.github.com/Thoth2020/11260019 but I'm not sure how to utilize it within my program. Is the name of my plugin VirtImage because of my namespace usage? And how do I actually use this in the program?

Comment: Install during app start: `new VirtImageProivder().Install(Config.Current);`
However, if you're basically changing the folder, you might just use the [VirtualFolder](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/virtualfolder) plugin instead.

Comment: Yeah, the path is the same once you shift the folder that you're looking in. This really does folder translation on the fly? That's pretty good. However, setting vpp to false means the images are only accessible when I use a query string, so if I don't use one... is that why you recommend to use a subfolder for VirtualPath instead of ~/? If I am understand this plugin correctly, any image path that starts with the VirtualPath string will be replaced with the Physical Path, so can I specify a Virtual Path that doesn't exist at all?

Comment: Yes, any virtual path can be used.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help and patience. It looks like I'm still going to have to talk to my CMS provider about some details, but you've gotten me as far as you can. If you like, you can post an answer and I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an existing controller or another HttpModule that is interfering with ImageResizer. One workaround is to use the fakeExtensions feature to avoid matching those routes. This makes your URLs look like `image.jpg.ashx?width=400` instead of `image.jpg?width=400`.

If your CMS abstracts away image storage, and does not implement VirtualPathProvider, you may need to implement an [IVirtualImageProvider](http://imageresizing.net/docs/extend/virtualimageprovider) to bridge the gap between your CMS data layer and ImageResizer.

Typically, however, you can use one of our existing storage plugins (SqlReader, S3Reader, VirtualFolder, RemoteReader) to access the data store directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. the imageResizer was saving and showing images just fine but none of the resizing and cropping or rotating functions would work.

**My problem solved by** simply adding two nuget packages with `Install-Package ImageResizer.WebConfig` and `Install-Package ImageResizer` to my **web** project. I had them on my **class library** project that was doing all the logic stuff but it seems they are also needed on the running assembly either web app or desktop.

Comment: Am using Angular project. but i hosted in live windows server only. I searched for nuget package for this installation. Am not able to get the package of imageresize.dll and imageresize.pdb. Can u please share me the files please.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's not safe sharing individual files but you should be able to get them from official sites.